# Why is the BFF pattern only applicable to SPA's?

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, access-token, refresh-token

I've been reading about BFF, more specifically about Duende.BFF, seeing if it could make sense for our solution of micro-frontends.
We already use Duende.IdentityServer for the token generation, so maybe we could save some time and maintenance moving the login application to a BFF, but I keep reading it's only meant for SPA's and I don't see why, can someone shed some light on the subject ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The role of a BFF in an OAuth context is to reduce the impact of cross site scripting exploits. These threats are specific to the browser, where malicious code might run, eg. from an npm dependency.

Some technology solutions may attempt to retrofit website solutions onto mobile apps. This may not be a good idea though - I wrote about why a mobile BFF does not usually make sense in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460963/flutter-oauth2-authentication-flow-with-custom-tabs-how-to-retrieve-session-c/77469099#77469099).

**WEB SETUPS**

A big focus with micro UIs is keeping the web code base manageable as it grows. Yet this does not mean each app should need to issue separate cookies and require a different login. Consider the following web routes:

```
/marketing1
/marketing2
```

In this case, you might want the routes to share the same cookie, which map to an access token with marketing privileges. API driven cookie issuing can be a good option here, to externalize cookie issuing from web development and keep code sizes small.

**FURTHER INFO**

At Curity, where I work, we did quite a bit of thinking about security in the browser a couple of years ago. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096336/why-is-bff-pattern-deemed-safer-for-spas) from a colleague of mine, which provides further detail on threats etc.

Comment: I've read Curity paper and there is one thing I am not 100% sure about. At some places, it sounds to me like it says that BFF is serving actual login form (separate html page, outside of SPA). Is that the case or is the login form just a part of the SPA?

Comment: Login forms are always presented or coordinated by the authorization server when using OAuth 2.0. They are never part of the SPA or irs BFF.

Comment: thanks! and then one more detail...is there any intermediate html page served by BFF (for redirects, setting cookie or anything) or are all the redirects done from/by SPA?

Comment: The BFF is strictly a utility API that sets cookies. It does not have or need a user interface.